# How to set the number of rows to be displayed in a table using tablesorter-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the tablesorter jquery plugin.(v2.20.1). I'm trying to set the number of rows per page on table render.
js:

```
var $table = $("#table").tablesorter({
     widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'filter'],
     widthFixed : true,
     ignoreCase: true,
     widgetOptions : {
        filter_columnFilters: false
    }   
}).tablesorterPager({               
    size: 2
});
```

but even when i set the size: 2, it still displays all the rows available on that page. I'm just looking to display 2 rows per page and using the simplePagination plugin, i'm paginating to get the next set of rows. Currently my table has 3 rows, so ideally 2 rows should be displayed when rendered and when i click the next button should take me to the next row on next page.
here is the tablesorter pager js:

```
items = $("table tbody tr");
perPage = 2;
numItems = items.length;
items.slice(perPage).hide();
$("#pagination").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    labelText: 'Showing',
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onInit: function (){
        startItem = ((this.currentPage*this.itemsOnPage)+1);
        endItem = ((startItem-1)+this.itemsOnPage);
        if(endItem > this.items){
            endItem = this.items;
        }
        $('#pagination').prepend(
        '<div class="pagination-addon">'+
        '<label class="pagination-label">'+this.labelText+'</label> '+
        '<label class="pagination-start-item">'+startItem+'</label> - '+
        '<label class="pagination-end-item">'+endItem+'</label> of '+
        '<label class="pagination-total-items">'+this.items+'</label>'+
        '</div>'
        );
    },

    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
        this.onInit();
        items.hide().slice(startItem-1, endItem).show();
    }   
});
```

html:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
     <td> items1</td>
     <td>items2</td>
     <td>items3</td></tr>
 </table>
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anLa1how/

Im not sure if there is any other way to set the page size in tablesorter, if not any ideas what could be wrong in here as i dont see the expected page size getting displayed.
Thanks!!!

Comment: What paging plugin you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using `simplePagination.js` instead of `jquery.tablesorter.pager.js`. But... did you realized that **you defined only 1 row so there was nothing to paginate**?

Here is the code and a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anLa1how/4/).

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>items1</td>
        <td>items2</td>
        <td>items3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>items4</td>
        <td>items5</td>
        <td>items6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>items7</td>
        <td>items8</td>
        <td>items9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var $table = $("#table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'filter'],
    widthFixed : true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_columnFilters: false
    }   
});

var items = $("table tbody tr");
var perPage = 2;
var numItems = items.length;
items.slice(perPage).hide();

$("#pagination").pagination({
    items: numItems,
    itemsOnPage: perPage,
    labelText: 'Showing',
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    onInit: function (){
        startItem = ((this.currentPage*this.itemsOnPage)+1);
        endItem = ((startItem-1)+this.itemsOnPage);
        if(endItem > this.items){
            endItem = this.items;
        }
        $('#pagination').prepend(
            '<div class="pagination-addon">'+
            '<label class="pagination-label">'+this.labelText+'</label> '+
            '<label class="pagination-start-item">'+startItem+'</label> - '+
            '<label class="pagination-end-item">'+endItem+'</label> of '+
            '<label class="pagination-total-items">'+this.items+'</label>'+
            '</div>'
        );
    },

    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { 
        this.onInit();
        items.hide().slice(startItem-1, endItem).show();
    }   
});
```